# java multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I'm executing a batch file using java command and reading batch data in text file putting in database. For example I have to run for 430 nodes within 15 min interval using same batch file. So I divided 430 node in 12 threads, so each thread contains 40 nodes pointing same batch file . But threads running parallel  are not able wait for the batch file command to complete. I can't make  wait for each thread, because all task should complete within 15 min. Any suggestions?

Below is piece of code running multi-threading.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < noOfMainThreads; i++) {
        // running 12 thread for 40 node 
        threadArr[i] = new Thread(runnableArr[i]);
        runnableArr[i] = new CodeBatchfile(nodeArr,nodeidArr);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfMainThreads; i++) {
        threadArr[i].start;
    } 


 class CodeBatchfile{  


    void run(){
        for (int i=1;i<nodename.length;i++) {
            // exciting batch file using 12 threads.
            cmd = filepath + " " + nodenamelocal;
            try {
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, bdir);
                process.waitFor();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception Running batch file" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "threads are not able wait for the batch file command to complete" Why not?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is a mess, and even contains unmatched curly brackets.

Comment: Is any batch file executing? You are should initialize `runnableArr[i]` before `threadArr[i] = new Thread(runnableArr[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead. Build a pipeline where each step works like this:

Create a job object which has all the information to do the task and which contains fields for the results. Create all job objects and put them into the queue for the service to run them.

So the first step would be to create 430 jobs to run the batch program. Each job would start the batch program and wait for it to terminate. After the batch terminates, you read the output and put that into the job instance.

Create an executor which runs N jobs in parallel. You will need to tune N; if it's a CPU intensive task, N == number of cores. if it's an IO intensive job, try higher values (2-4 times the CPU cores usually work well).

Put all the jobs into the executor's queue. Wait for jobs that finish, create new jobs from them and put them into the input queue of the executor.

Keep a job counter (started, finished) so you know when to stop.

[Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7).

Comment: Thank you very much,i will check and reply you back

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CyclicBarrier, barrier allow you to wait in specific point until all the threads reach to the barrier, so after executing the batch you should call the wait of the cyclicBarrier. a good code example can be found here:
[enter link description here](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/cyclicbarrier)